# Find the Height Number which divides N

Tags: algorithm, numbers, primes

I have to find the maximum number which is less than or equal to `SQUARE_ROOT(N)` and divides `N`. 
Most direct solution is of **O(SQUARE_ROOT(N))** , is there any **O(logN)** solution since number can be vary large in the range of **10^18**.

Answer (score 1):

If `N` equals to `p*q`, where `p` and `q` are prime numbers, you should find this primes first to answer your question. So this problem in general is not easier than [Integer factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization). And there is no known algorithm with O(logN) complexity.

> No algorithm has been published that can factor all integers in polynomial time, i.e., that can factor b-bit numbers in time O(b^k) for some constant k. Neither the existence nor non-existence of such algorithms has been proved, but it is generally suspected that they do not exist and hence that the problem is not in class P. The problem is clearly in class NP but has not been proved to be or not be NP-complete. It is generally suspected not to be NP-complete.

May be you could find something useful among different [factorization algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization#Factoring_algorithms).

Answer (score -1):

If N is composite, then

```
N = MaximumDivisor(N) * MinimumDivisor(N).
```

Comment: @ChristoferOhlsson How to find the smallest divisor in O(lg N)? Logically if I can find the smallest divisor I can find the largest divisor in O(1), so to me they are the same question

Comment: Exactly. But one trivially understands that looking for the smallest divisor is faster.

Comment: @ChristoferOhlsson Obviously it is nowhere near O(sqrt(N)) which is OP's question. Let N be any number which is product of two relative close prime (eg: 17*19 = 323),  how to find 17 which is O(lg N) ~ 8.3 but not O(sqrt(N)) ~ 17.9?

Comment: I can't take responsibility for OP wanting better than the state of the art. I was merely being helpful and informative.